# Script runs old version of .NET app even after replacing app with new version

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, batch-file, autosys

thank you for reading this.

Environment is an AutoSys scheduler running on Windows Server and the job calls a Perl script which grabs some files via FTP and processes them using a VB.NET application. We pushed a new version of the VB.NET app last week after a client requested a change.

The new version was pushed but when the script runs somehow the old code is being executed (we can tell by the logging output and result file). If I run the script from my desktop it executes the new code but when running from the scheduler it is running the old code.

This is difficult for us because the old version of the app is not available anymore. We copied over it with the new version (again, it works when I run it).

Any thoughts? I appreciate everyone taking the time to read this and trying to help me out!

Comment: Has the client duplicated the system to another location?  (You know that everyone would most likely ask this...) Have you thoroughly checked the Pearl scripts to ensure that there's not some call made in another branch?

Comment: Hey Westie, thank you. The client has not duplicated the code anywhere else and the Perl script goes one place. The script is very basic it is only a few lines. I was thinking maybe Windows is caching the app somehow.

Comment: Deleted last post - I was being stoopid (don't ask!).  I think you'll have to give more info as to the structure - I don't know a lot about Pearl - does it operate as a kind of web based script or are we looking at a service that processes the commands on a particular server (please excuse my ignorance).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic problem of the Autosys job environment being different than what you are running from the desktop. Does the command work when you run from the command prompt as the job's user ID on that server? If so from that command prompt, run set > user_env.txt

Copy the existing autosys job to a new job and replace the command with set > autosys_env.txt. Then run the job. Examine the user_env.txt and autosys_env.txt for any differences that may cause that error. Take a good look at the PATH values. You may need to run perl -v and the vb.net equivalent from the command prompt and job. If where.exe is installed that can be helpful to see what file is located.